# By Clicking an html link i want to open that url in browse?

Tags: uiwebview, iphone

I am opening an html page in web view and By Clicking an html link i want to open the given link in to web browser and my application should close.

Comment: Maybe adding a question might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement UIWebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegete method and inside it write

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
      }
}
```

Comment: it will call automatically when any action is taken on UIwebView... but you need to set UIWebView's delegate to that particular class...